# Get the function for a specific line in a C99 source file

Tags: c, static, line, analysis

I have a a large number of files which are all C99 and a long list of lines. Is there some tool which I could use to find out the function name for the lines? And how I do this with this tool.

I have for example this kind of file

```
static enum foo bar(int c)
{
    if (c < 30)
        return B1;
    else
        return B2;
}

static enum foo somethingelse(void)
{
    return B3;
}
```

The line information would be 4 `return B1;` and I need as answer at least "bar" but not "somethingelse"

The source code can only be compiled with GCC due to its dependencies.

Comment: Is the actual code always compilable? If yes, you can try replacing your `return B1;` with something like `THING_I_SEARCH_FOR` using e.g. `sed` and on compilation look at compiler error, which would be like `In function 'bar':` followed by actual errors (undeclared `THING_I_SEARCH_FOR` in this case).

Comment: It sounds like you want something analogous to the __FILE__ and __LINE__ preprocessor macros.  Unfortunately, the preprocessor doesn't know about functions, and I don't know of anything in the C language itself that can do this.

Comment: @muXXmit2X I think you mean `__func__`.

Comment: @muXXmit2X it might, I'm not sure.  If so, then it might be what OP wants, although is this only available in gcc, or is it included in one of the more recent ANSI C standards?

Comment: `__func__` doesn't work because it is not available as string for the preprocessor (it will be hacked in by GCC in a later step). And regex doesn't work to find the function name because regex can't parse C.

Funny enough, causing a compiler error is actually the best answer until now

Comment: And just as a remark, I never said that I search for an "phrase" but that I have line numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by finding the function name? If you know the line number, why not just open the source file and look the function name manually? What are you trying to do? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your question is not clear. But, have you tried a source indexer, like `cscope` or `lxr`?

Comment: Finding the function == getting the name of the function a line belongs to. And the number of lines are just too many to making this manual approach practical. These have to be associated with their function names to estimate the impact of a source code property for each function. It is basically used to identify which function has to be refactored due to this property. But it isn't relevant for this question what this property is or that the function has to be refactored for some reason(tm).

Comment: @jxh: I especially asked how I can use these tools to get from a line number to the function name this line number belongs to. And no, manually is no option

Comment: You didn't mention any tools you tried, and what the limitations were.

Comment: `__func__` has been part of the C language for 17 years. It is not a GCC extension.

Comment: Anyway, tool recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic on SO. Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If clang can *parse* your code, then just use libclang. Getting a callback called on each function declaration/definition and getting the line numbers from that isn't hard. Iterating over the tokens is also worth a try. Both can easily be done in a few hours even if one isn't familiar with the library.